# AES encryption in game server client/server

Tags: c++, encryption, aes, packet, initialization-vector

I run a game server, i got main server that handles all packets sent from players (clients).

I want to encrypt my packets via AES so that each packet should be unique (i think i need IV here) and that server should accept each encrypted packet one time only, so that if someone tried to sniff a packet he cannot send it again.

How do I do this?

P.S i code server and client in c++

Comment: Just use SSL, this is a problem which has already been solved more effectively than you can ever hope to.

Comment: Believe me that your vain attempts to "protect" your game wont help you at all. Im in some terms a "game hacker". Encryption is only important for man-in-the-middle attacks so that (external) attackers cant simply sniff the passwords of your users. However it wont help you against packet logger or custom clients in any way. Rather focus on server side protection (e.g log ill-formed packets which would never have been sended by the client due to assertions). But if somebody really wants to reverse your application you cant do a thing against it.

Comment: Also notice that a very important criterion should be performance: If you receive thousands of packets in a second, you must be able to encrypt and decrypt them fast. E.g: A very recent and famous MMORPG (1.5 years old) uses DHKE in conjunction with RC4.

Comment: A little addition to why your attempts are vain: An attacker, im talking about someone who wants to mangle with your game, e.g write bots or hacks, will focus on reversing the game client. He usually starts with the network layer. In some part of your game you **must** have a function which accepts unencrypted packets, so your abstraction layers will usually look like this: *game logic* --unencrypted--> *network layer* --encrypted--> *native networking*. You see: Ones a attacker is past the network layer he will be able to send artbitrary packets just by invoking a single method of yours.

Comment: well my major problem is sending same packet twice, because there is a very common hack being used when someone sniff a packet and resends it.

Comment: If he is interessted in more, he can now simply start to reverse your network layer, find out which methods are responsible for encryption, which for decryption. In the end he will know the exact algrorithm you use for encryption and will be able to reimplement it. This isnt really a big deal.

Comment: Believe me that your best protection is those implemented in components unaccessable to a hacker, which is usually the server. The most basic rule of thumb is: Never trust the client, check every value he sends you for correctness.

Comment: yes i know, but this will at least slow hackers down, because 99% of hackers barely can code a "sniffer" to send/receive packets

Comment: @user3356751 No this is a totally wrong assumption. You dont have to fear scripter kiddies (they can barely do anything without adults). You have to fear those capable of more. And what im trying to explain you: Its irrelevant how hard you try, an expirienced hacker will always find a way. Network encryption is usually no hurdle at all. However I know about 4 (critical) exploits in various online games which based on simply swapping some items ids, because some devs just forgot to check whether the id is actually correct.

Comment: It's useless to use AES for gaming purposes, especially because you will have performance issues e.g: lag. If you really want to encrypt traffic you better develop your own algorithm, something that will be random all the time and it will be very fast for encrypt/decrypt. If you are still interested in this, contact me via email and I will help you.

Comment: @Paranaix can we get in touch ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use some kind of SSL API like OpenSSL, but this may be overkill in your scenario as you would need to use certificates etc. There is a open source Rijndael (the algorithm that AES uses) C++ implementation [here](https://github.com/h2so5/libatc/blob/master/Rijndael.h).

Here is an example of its usage:

```
void testEncryptBlock()
{
    const int nCharacters = 16;
    char szHex[33];
    char *EncryptedData = new char[nCharacters + 1];
    CRijndael rijndael;
    int result = rijndael.MakeKey("abcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefgh");

    // Add some dummy data for the sake of the demo
    EncryptedData = (char*)memset(EncryptedData, 255, nCharacters); // 0xfffff...

    result = rijndael.EncryptBlock(EncryptedData);

    ... // Do something with the data

    delete [] EncryptedData;
}
```